# Slim 3.8 framework failing to route

Tags: php, slim

I have been using slim for sometime now, today I updated to 3.8 and out of the box I noticed something

```
 $app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {
 return 'Slim working';
});



$app->get('/hello', function ($request, $response) {
return 'Slim hello also working';
});
```

The first method call works, the second one gives me the `Object not found!` error, I do not understand what is wrong, could someone help me understand.

So my folder structure is like `appname/public/index.php` I run the first method by simply calling `appname/public/` for the second one I run it like `appname/public/hello`

Comment: it will be good , if you can attach error snippet.

Comment: `appname/public/index.php/hello` if you didn't rewrite the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add .htaccess file in your root directory (most probably appname/public) with following rule

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

hopefully it will work.